# has_many :through across multiple databases

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql-server, postgresql, tiny-tds

Ok I started writing this wanting help with has_many :through across multiple databases and still do, but I found something odd and maybe I am missing something.

So what I am doing:

I have

Rails 3.2

1 MSSQL DB table called deployments

1 POSTGRESQL DB table called reports

with a POSTGRESQL DB table for joining called associations

```
class Deployment < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.primary_key = :id
  establish_connection "deploy"
  self.abstract_class = true
  self.table_name = 'deployments'

  has_many :associations
  has_many :reports, through: :associations

end

class Report < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.primary_key = :id 
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy

  has_many :associations
  has_many :deployments, through: :associations

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :comments, allow_destroy: true
  validates :weekending, presence: true, uniqueness: true
end

class Association < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :deployment_id, :report_id
  belongs_to :deployment
  belongs_to :report
end
```

The creation of the association works fine I get both ID's populated in the table, but then when I try and get the data out I get the following:

```
report = Report.find(16)

report.deployments

!! #<ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: TinyTds::Error: Invalid object name 'associations'.: EXEC sp_executesql N'SELECT [deployments].* FROM [deployments] INNER JOIN [associations] ON [deployments].[id] = [associations].[deployment_id] WHERE [associations].[report_id] = 16'>
```

but and this is what I find odd, if I do this around the other way:

```
deployment = Deployment.find('0004d1bf-c49f-4310-85cd-222806d2eb78')

deployment.reports
[#<Report id: 15, weekending: "2019-01-17", visible: true, user_id: 5, news: "asdf", created_at: "2014-05-14 02:15:05", updated_at: "2014-05-14 02:15:05">]
```

Which is what I would expect, so anyone tell me why its not working the other way?

Comment: How are you indicating to rails that the tables are on different rdbms? Because it thinks they're together in that failing query.

Comment: @Richard, I am just using the establish_connection "deploy"

Comment: I was looking at a gem called st-elsewhere but it has been touched in 5 years

Comment: Having 2 DB servers for the same app is a sure recipe for disaster.

Comment: As helpful as that is @Alexandros, there are just some things that can't be helped :(

Answer (score 0):

Since it is a has amny one error i see in your code is report.deployment
it should be

```
repost.deployments
```

so in the model

```
has_many deployments
```

Comment: sorry that was just a typo when writing this, that is, how it is in the code

Comment: I see now, i notice that your id used in find is not the standard id, and you do not have a foreign key in your relationship to map it to the new one, so rails is trying to put '0004d1bf-c49f-4310-85cd-222806d2eb78' into the origin int column. tell me if that solves it.

Comment: I have changed a few things and got a little futher, but started another question - 
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23873852/rails-assication-not-saving-ids)